# I can not delete books from library management system in c language

Tags: c

function is not deleting books from file, it should delete the isbn number of the book provided and if we again enter that isbn number if book which has been deleted it should display the msg of "no record found" but instead it again display the information of book i.e file is not deleted

```
void deletingbooks() //displaying only deleting books function
  {
    system("cls");
    int d;
    char findbook;
    char another = 'y';
    while (another == 'y') //infinite loop
    {
      system("cls");

      printf("Enter the Book ID to  delete:");
      scanf("%d", & d);
      fp = fopen("library.dat", "rb+");
      rewind(fp);
      while (fread( & info, sizeof(info), 1, fp) == 1) {
        if (info.isbn == d) {
          printf("The book record is available\n\n\n\n");

          printf("Book name is %s\n\n", info.name);

          printf("Author name is %c\n\n", info.Author);
          findbook = 't';
        }
      }
      if (findbook != 't') {

        printf("No record is found modify the search\n\n");
        if (getch())
          mainmenu();
      }
      if (findbook == 't') {

        printf("Do you want to delete it?(Y/N):\n");
        if (getch() == 'y') {
          fd = fopen("test.dat", "wb+"); //temporary file for delete
          rewind(fp);
          while (fread( & info, sizeof(info), 1, fp) == 1) {
            if (info.isbn != d) {
              fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
              fwrite( & info, sizeof(info), 1, fd); //write all in tempory file except that
            } //we want to delete
          }
          fclose(fd);
          fclose(fp);
          remove("library.dat");
          rename("test.dat", "library.dat"); //copy all item from temporary file to fp except that
          fp = fopen("library.dat", "rb+"); //we want to delete
          if (findbook == 't') {

            printf("The record is sucessfully deleted\n");

            printf("\nDelete another record?(Y/N)");
          }
        } else
          mainmenu();
        fflush(stdin);
        another = getch();
      }
    }

    mainmenu();
  }
```

Comment: consider using `fclose(fp)` from time to time...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - Perhaps `fflush` instead?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour

Comment: Perhaps using _ncurses_ library instead of using `syslem("cls")`

Comment: And please sort out the indentation

Comment: What is `info`?

Comment: Please check the return values from `fopen` and `scanf`